# How to use std::copy() to copy to a destination that is pointer to the beginning of a generic buffer of bytes?

Tags: c++, vector, std

In this example, let's say myVector is a std::vector of some custom type `myType`.

```
unsigned char* bufferPtr = myBufferOfBytes.getBufferPointer();
std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), bufferPtr);
```

Is this possible to do somehow, or can I only do this using `std::memcpy()`?

Comment: I'm sure that you've ignored it for the sake of brevity, but to everyone else, don't forget to check your when you're about to write to a buffer like that!

Comment: Check your what? There's a typo in your comment.

Comment: Oops, check your bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uninitialized_copy` and cast the `bufferPtr` to the expected type:

```
std::uninitialized_copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), reinterpret_cast<myType*>(bufferPtr));
```

The usual warnings apply:

- make sure that `bufferPtr` is long enough for the entire copy;
- `bufferPtr` must originally have been allocated as an array of `unsigned char`, or else you may invoke undefined behavior (use `std::copy` if the array was originally allocated as `myType`);
- `bufferPtr`'s alignment must be greater or equal to `alignof(myType)`;
- if `myType` is not trivially destructible, then `bufferPtr` must be deallocated in a way that is aware of it.

Comment: And make sure that the buffer is properly aligned to be used as `myType`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, thanks for the reminder. I'm expanding the list of warnings at the moment.

Comment: Alternatively, treat `myVector` as unsigned char, and copy them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, that would only be valid if `myType` is trivially copyable, though.

Comment: Depending on what currently lies in the buffer, you might need some placement news first, even for `myType = int`. At least formally. [reinterpret\_cast creating a trivially default-constructible object](//stackoverflow.com/q/40873520)

Comment: @zneak: True--but most code like this depends on that anyway (e.g., for copying data over the network and recovering something meaningful on the other end).

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule unless the buffer already consists of `myType` objects, which seems unlikely given the setup. (Your second bullet point incorrectly mentions unsigned char)

Comment: @M.M, what is the solution then? Cast `myType*` to `unsigned char*` instead of `unsigned char*` to `myType*`?

Comment: @M.M, I changed it to `uninitialized_copy`, as it appears to be legal to use an array of `unsigned char` to provide storage for any object.

Comment: @zneak OK, I think that is valid now